# File paths manipulation in scala

Tags: scala

Is there some nice way to safely manipulate file paths in Scala, transcending naive string manipulation?

I mean smart concatenation that adds missing slashes between path parts, Unix v.s. Windows slashes, automatically escaping spaces in paths, etc?

What would be a nice Java fallback for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
import java.io.File

val a = "abc/def"
val b = "ghi/jk"
new File(a,b).getPath
// res0: String = abc/def/ghi/jk
```

Comment: what about if the file not (yet) exists in the filesystem?

Comment: Java's `File` doesn't use the file system; it just wraps the file name so you can do stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

These days, [better-files](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files) is one of the simplest and most widely used.

Previous answer: *If you're willing to use an external library, [rapture.io](https://github.com/propensive/rapture) makes it about as easy as it can get.*

Comment: That link is broken :-(